# IIS 10 Form Authentication non ASP.NET app Login page blocked by 401.2

Tags: iis, forms-authentication

I configured FormAuthentication on IIS 10 like so:
[image]

This is a website that is an angular app and /login is an actual route that should bring up login page.
When I hit the main page (/) it does get redirected correctly to
/login?ReturnUrl=%2f
but the browser shows :

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

As far as I can tell it happens before the login page gets a chance to see the request (no breakpoints get hit).

Did I configure IIS incorrectly and if so what should it have been?

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see details about 401.2 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.